# How do I add a variable's value to an array and then have the variable change value and the array keep the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to add a variable's string to an array and then I need to change the value of the variable without changing the value in the string.

```
//Random Number Generator
let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89173458943);
//JS array
let array = [number];
console.log(array);
```

The a new number is generated every time and I need the array to save the number then add a new spot for another number.

I have tried local storage API but that does not work. This resulted in the last inputed number saving even when I reopened the page. I also can't find any methods or properties that work on the array. That resulted in nothing. I really need help.

Comment: Use `array.push(number)` to add another number to the array.

Comment: array.push works. But is that what you are looking for? The question is ambiguous. Explain with an example please

Answer (score 0):

Save/load the array in/from the local storage with JSON.stringify/parse:

```js
//Random Number Generator
let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89173458943);
//JS array
let array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my-random-array')) ?? [];
array.push(number);
localStorage.setItem('my-random-array', JSON.stringify(array));

console.log(array);
```